# Find and replace surrounding words in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

Consider the following:

```
The cat jumped over the wall
The cat sat on the wall
The cat strolled along the wall
The cat hid under the hedge
The horse considered the wall
```

I would like to replace "cat * wall" with "dog * bridge" in emacs resulting in:

```
The dog jumped over the bridge
The dog sat on the bridge
The dog strolled along the bridge
The cat hid under the hedge
The horse considered the wall
```

I know i can find replace just cat -> dog and accept each example but I am wondering how I can do it all automatically

Comment: Use `M-x replace-regexp`

Comment: Use a capture group to get the part between `cat` and `wall` so you can copy it into the replacement.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It would be better asked on Emacs.SE or SuperUser.com.

Comment: What regex is it? "cat .* wall" and "dog .* bridge" turns the first line to "The dog .* bridge"

Comment: Like I said, you need to use a capture group and back-reference to copy the part in between to the replacement. What are you missing?

Comment: if you don't know what a capture group is, it's time to read a regexp tutorial.

Comment: Read the Info section on Regexps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Barmar

The regex I was looking for was

```
cat \(.*\) wall -> dog \1 bridge
```